# Позиция обрезанного изображения в блоке

Tags: html, css

У меня есть изображения. Все они большего размера чем блок, в котором он должен лежать. Я задал размеры блока которые мне нужны и `overflow: hidden;` изображение обрезалось по тем размерам, которые мне нужны, но показывается левая верхняя часть. Как мне можно двигать изображения, чтоб отображаемую часть можно было выставить на то место изображения, куда я хочу. Пробовал `margin`, но значение `margin` получается отрицательным, что есть не `good practice`.

Comment: Свойство background-position пробовали?

Comment: Что бы получить внятный ответ, вопрос тоже должен быть внятным... Покажи код...

Comment: @Air человек выше понял...

Comment: @RealPeha спасибо большое

Comment: Я тоже понял.... Только на сайте есть правило...  Вопросы надо оформлять в соответствии с требованиями формата сайта...

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать на своих изображениях свойство **object-fit**.
Или использовать его как фон со свойством  *background-size: cover , contain* и т.д..

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.container img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
.container2 img {
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}


.oroginal {
width: 300px;
}

.oroginal img {

  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
object-fit: cover; -
<div class="container">
<img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/5989c7590cf070775150d3c866e03bd7/1523701877/72880/1237156/Avances_tecnologicos_actuales_1.jpg" >
</div>
object-fit: contain; -
<div class="container2">
<img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/5989c7590cf070775150d3c866e03bd7/1523701877/72880/1237156/Avances_tecnologicos_actuales_1.jpg" >
</div>
<hr>

background-size: cover; - 
<div class="container" style="
background-image: url(http://i.piccy.info/i9/5989c7590cf070775150d3c866e03bd7/1523701877/72880/1237156/Avances_tecnologicos_actuales_1.jpg);
       background-size: cover;
       background-position: center  center;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
"></div>
<hr>

original img -
<div class="oroginal">
<img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/5989c7590cf070775150d3c866e03bd7/1523701877/72880/1237156/Avances_tecnologicos_actuales_1.jpg" >
</div>
```